# How to do <xor> in python e.g. enc_price = pad <xor> price

Tags: python, xor, hmac

I am new to crypto and I am trying to interpret the below code.  Namely, what does `<xor>` mean?

I have a secret_key secret key.  I also have a unique_id. I create pad using the below code.

```
pad = hmac.new(secret_key, msg=unique_id, digestmod=hashlib.sha1).digest()
```

Once the pad is created, I have a price e.g. 1000. I am trying to follow this instruction which is pseudocode:

```
enc_price = pad <xor> price
```

In Python, what is the code to implement `enc_price = pad <xor> price`?  What is the logic behind doing this?

As a note, a complete description of what I want to do here here:
https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/rtb/response-guide/decrypt-price

[developers.google.com/ad-exchange/rtb/response-guide/decrypt-price](https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/rtb/response-guide/decrypt-price)

Thanks

Comment: The OP wants to implement "[DoubleClick Ad Exchange Real-Time Bidding Protocol](https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/rtb/response-guide/decrypt-price)". Since google provides sample [python code](https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/rtb/test-guide#initial), it is not worth reinventing the wheel.

Comment: The above statement is not true.  The sample code does not deal with price decryption at all.

Comment: Last I heard, Bruce Schneier seemed to be saying that one time pads aren't very effective, because they aren't really one time.

Comment: @Tampa: sorry, I have no access to this code and seems like I guessed wrong from the docs. But now that I understand your question better, I feel less inclined to pursue an answer, since I think you should ask the vendor for a Python implementation or hire someone to port the given implementations from other languages to Python. Don't get me wrong, if you have a deadline you better seek for professional assistance instead of volunteer help.

Answer (score 3):

The binary (I assume that's what you need) `xor` is `^` in python:

```
>>> 6 ^ 12
10
```

Binary xor works like this (numbers represented in binary):

```
     1234

6  = 0110
12 = 1100
10 = 1010
```

For every pair of bits, if their sum is `1` (bits 1 and 3 in my example), the resulting bit is `1`. Otherwise, it's `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You mean "[Binary bitwise operations](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations)"?

> The & operator yields the bitwise AND of its arguments, which must be plain or long integers. The arguments are converted to a common type.
>
> The ^ operator yields the bitwise XOR (exclusive OR) of its arguments, which must be plain or long integers. The arguments are converted to a common type.
>
> The | operator yields the bitwise (inclusive) OR of its arguments, which must be plain or long integers. The arguments are converted to a common type.

[update]

Since you can't xor a string and a number, you should either:

- convert the number to a string padded to the same size and xor each byte (may give you all sort of strange "escape" problems with some chars, for example, accidentally generating invalid unicode)
- use the raw value (20 byte integer?) of the digest to xor and make an hexdigest of the resulting number.

Something like this (untested):

```
pad = hmac.new(secret_key, msg=unique_id, digestmod=hashlib.sha1).digest()
rawpad = reduce(lambda x, y: (x << 8) + y, 
            [ b for b in struct.unpack('B' * len(pad), pad)])
enc_price = "%X" % (rawpad ^ price)
```

[update]

The OP wants to implement "[DoubleClick Ad Exchange Real-Time Bidding Protocol](https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/rtb/response-guide/decrypt-price)".

This very article tells there are some sample python code available:

> **Initial Testing**
>
> You can test your bidding application internally using requester.tar.gz. This is a test python program that sends requests to a bidding application and checks the responses. The program is available on request from your Ad Exchange representative.

Comment: And now you get to deal with "Why doesn't `<str> ^ <int>` work?!".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: he sould not use a digest, but the raw hash, then extract a hexdigest from the resulting operation.

Comment: Hi...I am tryijg to do the following.  https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/rtb/response-guide/decrypt-price

Comment: In the section of decrypt.  I have to take what is given.

Comment: @Tampa: why the hell did you started with a Python example that looks nothing like the documented algorithm instead of linking to that page? Please update your question with the relevant information instead of commenting here (and provide sample values).

Comment: There is no python code available. But I will try what you have done.  I am sure you have a better understanding on that page than I do.

Comment: Please take out that statement on requester.tar.gz.  There is no sample code and that is not how that program works.  I know, I have it.

Comment: @Tampa: sorry, I have no access to `requester.tar.gz`, seems like I wrongly guessed that since it is used to test requests and responses it would have an implementation of the algorithm. Still, I think stackoverflow is not a substitute for your vendor support channels so I'm not inclined to pursue a solution for this question.

Answer (score 0):

The pad, and the plaintext "price" are each to be interpreted as a stream of bits. For each corresponding bit in the two streams, you take the "exclusive OR" of the pair of bits - if the bits are the same, you emit 0, if the bits are different, you emit 1. This operation is interesting because it's reversible: plaintext XOR pad -> ciphertext, and ciphertext XOR pad -> plaintext.

However, in Python, you won't usually do the XORing yourself because it's tedious and overly complex for a newbie; you want to use a popular encryption library such as [PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

I did it so

```
def strxor(s1,s2):
    size =  min(len(s1),len(s2))

    res = ''
    for i in range(size):
        res = res + '%c' % (ord(s1[i]) ^ ord(s2[i]))
    return res
```